# haml remove whitespace before dot after adding rails link_to, mail_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm writing text in haml:

```
Blab bla for any questions contact us on me@foo.com.
```

so the haml looks like

```
%p
  Blab bla for any questions contact us on
  = mail_to 'me@foo.com'
  &#46;
```

*note &#46; is dot in ascii, I can also replace that line with `= '.'` (render string dot)*

but the rendered text looks like

```
Blab bla for any questions contact us on me@foo.com .
```

difference is that whitespace before dot at the end

the solution I came up with and works is

```
%p
  Blab bla for any questions contact us on
  = mail_to('me@foo.com') + '.'
```

it's just I'm looking for best practice :) thx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd use this:

```
%p
  Blab bla for any questions contact us on #{mail_to('me@foo.com')}.
```

Also see [the Haml FAQ](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.FAQ.html#q-punctuation):

> Expressing the structure of a document and expressing inline formatting are two very different problems. Haml is mostly designed for structure, so the best way to deal with formatting is to leave it to other languages that are designed for it.

In this case you don't need another language, just interpolate the function.

Comment: one more question is this just local rails thing or suported by haml by default when using any ruby framework (sinatra, padrino f.e. ) ?

Comment: @equivalent8 It's normal Haml behaviour: http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#ruby_interpolation_

Answer (score 6):

If you were to use the `==` notation, for the line with mail_to, you should be able to do what you want, likle this:

```
== #{mail_to 'me@foo.com'}.
```

The `==` notation performs interpolation for the entire line.

Comment: yep, this is working, and it's  more elegant than my solution. Will se what other solutions are there :)

Answer (score 5):

HAML has [a bunch of helpers](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html) to solve such situations easily. `succeed` solves trailing dot problem.

```
= succeed '.' do
   = link_to t('info.terms'), info_path(:terms)
```